# Cant change size of wallpaper (stock or from home/pictures) 13.10 using gnome3

Tags: gnome, nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

Anyone got any idea why there are no options to adjust selected desktop wallpaper (ie Zoom / scale etc) in ubuntu 13.10 and gnome3 (works fine in unity but i really dont like using it).
Same issue for stock wallpaper and my own photos in /home/pictures:

General system specs
Pentium E2160 @ 1.8Ghz x 2
GeForce 7300GS/PCIe/SSE2
64Bit
2.0Gb Mem:
Dual monitor setup using 2 x acer LCD screens (AL1716 and AL2202W) latter is selected as main display

System updates all done
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorted now, thanks @guntbert for the speedy answer. Odd how gnome seemto have missed these options in the standard UI though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust  your gnome desktop  wallpaper  using `dconf-editor` tool.

Open it by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> and enter `dconf-editor` . Now go to  **org** --> **gnome** --> **desktop** --> **background** --> **picture-options** and change its value whatever you need.

[image]

Alternatively you can change it using command line.

Use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options "centered"` to make your background centered.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)