# Desktop picture properties

Tags: 16.04, gnome, desktop-background

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, GNOME Shell v3.18.5
I can't find out how can I change my wallpaper properties such as to fill/to title/etc. Thanks.
Edit:  Ok, I found it [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442043/). I just wanted to find a little bit more simple way to do that. I'm pretty sure there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNOME Tweak Tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`) - in Desktop section you can set background mode from the list.

Comment: Yup, exactly that.  Was about to post this exact answer myself just now